# Updating the Frei0r video plugin in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, plugins

Does anyone know how to update the Frei0r video effects plug-in in Ubuntu 12.04?

I can't find a PPA and I need it updated for Openshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gnome-video-effects-frei0r](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-video-effects-frei0r) [image: Install gnome-video-effects-frei0r] will install version 1.1.22 of the Frei0r plugins in all Ubuntu versions, including 12.04, 12.10, and 13.04.

A newer but possibly unstable version 1.4.0 can be [installed from the ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) below (but OpenVC support is unstable and [will be disabled for 12.04](https://launchpad.net/~sunab/+archive/kdenlive-release)):

- **ppa:sunab/kdenlive-release**